# Listen to keyUp and down events inside component nested in react-popper

Tags: reactjs, keyevent, popper.js

I have a parent component that uses the react-popper library like so

```
<Manager
  className=''
  data-component-name={componentName}
  data-store-name={...}
  onKeyUp={(e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 38) {

    }
  }}
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 40) {
      console.log('cls list', e);
    }
  }}>
  <Target
    className={''}>
    <SearchInput
      componentName={...}
      storeName={...}
      placeholderLabel={...}
      refCallback={...}
      disabled={...}/>
  </Target>
  <Popper placement='bottom'
          modifiers={popperModifiers}
          className={'myClass'}>
    <SearchResults componentName={...}
                   storeName={...}/>}
  </Popper>
</Manager>
```

So inside the Popper JSX component, I have the child component **SearchResults** which is a parent to another component as follows

```
<div>
  {nodes.length
    ? nodes.map(node =>
      <TreeNode key={...} node={node} {...dataProps} />)
    : <div className=''>
      {
        null
      }
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

The problem here is that I would like the above wrapping Div to listen to the keyUp and down events, but it doesn't not even after using the `tabIndex='0'`, it only works when I put it on the popper manager like up above, I would like to achieve something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSNgf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Search in your code (Target, SearchInput, SearchResults components) to see if you have already catch `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` events and `stopPropagation` on them. Remove the `stopPropagation` if there are.